# How to read only the names of files inside the 7zip file?

Tags: java, 7zip

I have the requirement to read only the names of files inside 7zip file using java.I do not want to decompress the file .

I

String archiveFilename="002.7z";

```
        SevenZFile sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(new File(archiveFilename));
            SevenZArchiveEntry entry = sevenZFile.getNextEntry();

            System.out.println(entry.toString());
            //Enumeration<? extends SevenZFile> entries = (Enumeration<? extends SevenZFile>) sevenZFile.getEntries();
           // System.out.println(entries);
            while (entry != null) 
            {
                    final byte[] contents = new byte[(int) entry.getSize()];
                    int off = 0;
                    while ((off < contents.length)) 
                    {
                        final int bytesRead = sevenZFile.read(contents, off, contents.length - off);
                        off += bytesRead;
                    }
                    System.out.println(new String(contents, "UTF-8"));              
                entry = sevenZFile.getNextEntry();
            }

}
```

I am using this code

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986689/how-to-read-contents-for-file-which-is-in-7z-extension-file/22022733

Comment: Did you read the javadoc for `SevenZFile` and `SevenZArchiveEntry`?